# css for the table layout

Tags: html, css

I have created a table and the firebug shows something like this. I want the color to be for the whole div tag in the left column

```
<table style="width:100%;">
<tr><td style="vertical-align: top;">
<div style="float:right;background:silver;width:150px;height:300px;position:relative;">
</div></td>
<td>
<div>
 my table....


 blah blah....
</div>
</td></tr>
</table>
```

My table looks something like this.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> I want the color to be for the whole div tag in the left column

The color **is** for the "whole div tag" but the DIV is not sized to the dimensions of the column, which I assume is what you want.

### Options

- Don't float the `DIV`. This will use the default layout of `display:block` which will provide 100% width. You can then set its height to 100% or a specific height: http://jsfiddle.net/QCKMP/1/. Note
  that this will require an explicit height being set on the table cell or on the DIV.
- Or, set the background color directly on the table cell.
- Better option, remove the table altogether and use `DIVs` (or other, more semantic elements like `NAV` and `ARTICLE`) for layout.

Comment: Though I give the height as 100%, there is a white space left of the div tag, I am not sure why it is showing that

Comment: Because you have it floated? Did the JS fiddle I posted work for you?

Comment: No it didn't have any affect on my table. Though it looks good on JS fiddle

Comment: You also have width explicitly set in your code. That would cause space next to the DIV too.

Comment: If i remove the width the right td occupies the whole table hiding the left td. I have tried using div instead but it is messing up the whole page. So I wanted to include in the table just like google does in the gmail. I am trying to achieve a gmail kind of look for the website.

Comment: You can set a width on the left TD, but if you set a different width on the DIV, then there will be a gap. Here is a fiddle demonstrating: http://jsfiddle.net/QCKMP/2/

Answer (score -1):

try something like this

```
        <html>
        <body >
        <table style="width:100%; border:1px solid red;">
        <tr><td style="vertical-align:top; float:left; padding-left:20px; border:1px solid red">
        <div style="float:right;background:silver;width:150px;height:300px;position:relative;">
        </div></td>
        <td>
        <div>
         my table....
         blah blah....
        </div>
        </td></tr>
        </table>
        </body>
        </html>
```

**checkout jsfiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/Q4vS8/

Comment: I do not want the white space to the left of the silver div. I am not not sure why there is a gap between the td's

Comment: your image having some gap that's why i am setting

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear. I see the gap and I don't want the gap so I posted to get that fixed so that whole td tag has the color and no white space between the td's

Comment: checkout: http://jsfiddle.net/Q4vS8/2/  what type of output you want ? pls post image type

Comment: Yes, it should look like something in the above link, I got it working though.

Comment: I need another suggestion, I am trying to figure out how to have a line below ABCD in the table. If I add border style to the table it creates around ABCD and not below it. Any suggestions? http://jsfiddle.net/Q4vS8/5/